# How to disable dots as delimiters in sqldeveloper (import data from csv)?

Tags: csv, oracle-sqldeveloper, delimiter

I am trying to import data to oracle database from csv file. In csv file i use "," as separator. I have problem with column "amount" where I have to put amount of 2 decimal places separated by a dot. I don`t know why, sql developer treats the dot as separator even though the delimiters I have selected only ",".

How to disable dot as delimiter/separator in sql developer? (I need only "," as delimiter/separator).

Comment: Are the values enclosed within double-quotes?

Comment: No, in table it`s a numeric type column

Comment: In your CSV file, are the values enclosed within double quotes? Like `"SCOTT" , "2000.50"`

Comment: Yes I add duble quotes but it dosn`t help. (like this: "-640.68",17663,null,B0045/614001623,)

Comment: How did you generate the CSV file? From SQL Developer itself?

Comment: from excel 2003 -> csv seperated coma file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have imported csv file from sql developer and its working fine.

i have attached snapshot while import:

[image]

My csv file content is as below:

11.22,11.56

21.32,14.46

31.42,17.36

41.52,20.26

51.62,23.16

61.72,26.06

71.82,28.96.

Can u able to put csv file content and table structure?